# Nodejs GM module ImageMagick - strange Error

Tags: node.js, heroku, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I have a very strange error. I'm using MAC OS X 10.9.5.
When i use some functions from GM (`npm install gm`) like resize or something else i got this error.

```
    events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    Error: spawn ENOENT
        at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

I have found many threads about it and according to them i have installed graphicksmagic and imagemagick with brew to system.

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install graphicsmagick
```

It was working for a while but for no reason it starts to showing the above error again.

I checked that i have installed imagemagick and graphicksmagick in system and its working from terminal.
I checked if i have it in $PATH and its there.

If i run this in nodejs it shows correct version of imagemagick in console, so i assume path is ok in nodejs.

```
var sys = require('sys')    
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
                if(error)
                        sys.puts(error);
                if(stderr)
                        sys.puts(stderr);
                sys.puts(stdout);
        }
exec("identify --version", puts);
```

This is code which is crashing:

```
gm(request(url), thumbName)
                .resize('300', '300', '^')
                .gravity('Center')
                .crop('300', '300')
                .toBuffer('JPG',function (err, buffer) {
                    var data = {
                        Bucket: bucket,
                        Key: thumbName,
                        Body: buffer,
                        ACL:'public-read',
                        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
                    };
                    s3.putObject(data, function(err, res) {
                       ....
                    });
```

Everything is working when i deploy it on heroku

Comment: Did you happen to find a work around for this??

Comment: Yes i've answered this question and mark answer as good.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tried adding the path but it did not work for me. I fixed it by using imagemagick directly instead of gm

Comment: Ah, i understand, you got some different problem. I think you can use GM also but require it  like this : var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF someone will have this issue i solved it. 
I add variable PATH to enviroment variables in node with this value
bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin